# Python code to append file in a formatted way

Tags: python, file, formatting, python-2.6

I would like to write/append in to the file in a formatted output using python, also how can i write the text in file with specific color/bold/italics ..etc

### Current Output:

```
text0   = sample
text1   = <property><name>hbase.regionserver.wal.codec</name><value>org.apache.hadoop</value>
recovery_directory = "warning":2147483648   
text3   = recovery_dir
text4   = manager_log_dir
```

### Expected Output:

```
text0              = sample
text1              = <property>
                     <name>hbase.regionserver.wal.codec</name>
                     <value>org.apache.hadoop</value>
recovery_directory = "warning":2147483648  
text3              = recovery_dir
text4              = manager_log_dir
```

### CODE :

```
def fappend(f,text):
        check=os.path.isfile(f)
        text=str(text) + "\n"
        if check == False:
           f1=open(f,'w')
        else:
           f1=open(f,'a')
        f1.write(text)
        f1.close()
        return

def format(item,length):
  out = item.ljust(length)
  return out;


def main():

rname = api    
for c in rname.get_config(view='full'):
    name = c.name
    val = c.value
    if val != None:
       text = format(config.name,5)
       item = text + "=  " + val
       fappend(file, item)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: If you want color/bold/italics you'll need to decide on some presentation protocol. For instance, you could write HTML and view the document in a web browser. Or you could colorize with terminal escape sequences. Pick one then we can propose a solution.

Comment: `text1` is kindof, but not quite, XML. What sort of rules does it follow? If it had an ampersand in one the text fields, would it be escaped to an xml entity like `&amp;` or left in tact? What about `>`, would it be `&gt;`?

Comment: Hi tdelaney, Thanks for your reply.

1. I am looking for colorize with terminal escape sequences
2. Tex1 will be my properties = corresponding values
3. Values are in multiple patterns which includes XML, JSON and simple text. So cannot have fixed rules on patterns.

Comment: Instead can have line break after fixed number of characters.